# GKE Control plane warm up

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I'm using Terraform v0.15.0 to deploy a zonal GKE cluster with 3 separate node pools which are being created right after the cluster. The initial node pool is being created with 1 node and is deleted when the cluster is ready. Then I use Helm provider to deploy some workload: first I deploy Nginx Ingress Chart. These two steps work fine. Right after Nginx Ingress Chart, I deploy our application that consists of 16 Deployments/Stateful Sets and related Services PVC, PV...
That step finishes after 10s and marks as finished and all looks good but there are no workloads in the cluster except for Nginx Ingress deployment. Instead, I see **REPAIR_CLUSTER** operation in running state:

```
% gcloud container operations list
NAME                              TYPE              LOCATION           TARGET                    STATUS_MESSAGE  STATUS  START_TIME                      END_TIME
operation-1621007628555-9d3ea30c  REPAIR_CLUSTER    europe-west1       <project_name_here>                       RUNNING    2021-05-14T15:53:48.555309083Z
```

Cluster status is **RECONCILING**:

```
% gcloud container clusters list 
NAME                      LOCATION           MASTER_VERSION    MASTER_IP       MACHINE_TYPE   
<cluster_name_here>       europe-west1-b     1.17.17-gke.4900  <ip_here>       e2-standard-2  1.16.15-gke.7800    6          RECONCILING
```

I already tried:

- [auto_repair](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_node_pool#auto_repair) and [auto_upgrade](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_node_pool#auto_upgrade) set to false;
- deploy regional cluster;
- use UNSPECIFIED release [channel](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_cluster#channel) which makes Kubernetes version fixed(no autoupdates).

When **REPAIR_CLUSTER** operation finished, the cluster is ready to handle my workload but it makes my pipeline failed. So my question is how to avoid that operation or how to warm up Google's resources in advance.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Launching a GKE cluster takes a while and you can't update it while stuff is in-progress. There is no way around that, stuff just takes time to run.

Comment: Think of it as a pipeline with the following steps:
1. Cluster creation - finishes successfully 
2. Deploying Nginx Ingress - finishes successfully.
3. Deploy an application - executed successfully, but finished in a short period of time and there is no workload in the cluster. I even can wait for some time before executing this step and it always causes cluster reconciling.

Comment: I'm still not seeing why this is a problem?

Comment: The problem is that I have to run the app deployment step twice and wait for some unpredictable delay. While REPAIR_CLUSTER is running control plane API is unreachable.

Comment: Can you add the Terraform config on your post? Also provide the repair events logs on Cloud logging. Does this also happen when you are deploying it manually? (no terraform)